# Using IOKit for USB communications in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, usb, iokit

I want to use IOKit for USB communications on iOS. My applications run using IOKit on OSX, but I need to port them to iOS. What's the best way to get started with IOKit on iOS? I know it's a private API, so how do I get access as a developer? Do I pull over the headers from OSX? Any tips for getting started?

Because IOKit is a private API on iOS, I know Apple will reject my app if I submit it to the App Store, but I'm developing an enterprise level application that will never be distributed via the App Store.

Comment: Did you solve the issue in iOS? Did you create a Driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the binary libIOKit.dylib for your target iOS application.

Might want to take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html

and
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: for iOS, do you need to create a Driver?

Comment: Those links are to macOS documentation, but the OP is asking about iOS. You cannot use IOKit directly on iOS, apparently.

Comment: If you are writing public application (app store) you are correct, you cannot use IOKit in iOS.